# USGS Topographic Map Online API?

Tags: openstreetmap, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, mapnik, united-states, topography

I am creating a website for a non-profit organization and would like to plot points on a map similar to this: http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=931d892ac7a843d7ba29d085e0433465

I am currently plotting points on google maps through its API, but it isn't a great solution and I have heard that Google has rights to that point. (Correct me if I'm wrong) Anyway, I was wondering if there was a good way to use the USGS Topo layer on the USGS website to plot points dynamically through javascript with an API or some other means... Is there anyway I can set this up through mapnik, similar to this (http://www.toposm.com/us/index.html)?

On another note I have to be "licensed" in order to access ArcGIS javascript API, don't I? Or is this incorrect?

Comment: I would recommend using TopOSM - http://www.toposm.com/us/index.html?zoom=13&lat=39.89614&lon=-105.31393&layers=B0TT covers the entire US.

Comment: You can add maps to Openlayers with the http://raster.nationalmap.gov/ArcGIS/rest/services/ an example of it working http://jsfiddle.net/aguiguy/ZAZN8/

Comment: Oh my gosh this is so powerful. Wow.... Openstreet maps javascript API with multiple layers. So nice... Mapperz - If I were plotting "private" data on the server do they log that?

Answer (score 2):

The ArcGIS Javascript API in and of itself is free. However, to add your own content you would need a license to ArcGIS Server.

You could use arcgisonline.com to create a map similar to the link you provided and add a spreadsheet that contains the plot points you want. This is a free service, however, I think there is a limit on the amount of features you can add (somewhere around 1000). All you need to get is an ESRI global ID if you don't have one already.